# "Using MLAPI" gives error message, even when I have MLAPI installed

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, compiler-errors

I have MLAPI *(https://docs-multiplayer.unity3d.com/docs/migration/install/index.html)* installed with Tanks multiplayer *(https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/templates/tutorials/tanks-multiplayer-mlapi-photon-mirror-69172#description)*, and when I import the tanks multiplayer code for MLAPI, I get the error: **"error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MLAPI' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"**, even though it is installed, and I don't know what to do

[image of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYccg.png)

[image of the packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RL2Ol.png)

Comment: Maybe some version mismatch?

Comment: @derHugo both are on compatible versions, they were working yesterday, which is why I am so confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to import MLAPI like so
using Unity.Netcode;

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I could have sworn that it was "using MLAPI"  but this worked, thanks!